# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: party::getArrival()

Tags: c++, xcode4

I have a header file for the `party` class called `party.h`:

```
#ifndef party_h
#define party_h

#include <iostream>

class party{
private:
    int people;
    int waitTime;
    bool waiting;
    int arrival;

public:
    party();
    party(int, int);
    int getPeople();
    void setPeople(int);
    bool isWaiting();
    void setWaiting(bool);
    void setWaitTime(int);
    int getwaitTime();
    void setArrival(int);
    int getArrival();
    int getTotalTime(int);
    void decrement();
};

#endif
```

And its implementation in `party.cpp`:

```
#include "party.h"

party::party(){}

party::party(int numPeople, int a){
    people = numPeople;
    arrival = a;
}
int party::getPeople(){
    return people;
}

void party::setPeople(int p){
    people = p;
}

bool party::isWaiting(){
    return waiting;
}

void party::setWaiting(bool w){
    waiting = w;
}

void party::setWaitTime(int t){
        waitTime = t;
}

int party::getwaitTime(){
    return waitTime;
}

void party::setArrival(int a){
    arrival =a; 
}

int party::getTotalTime(int current){
    return (current-arrival);
}
```

Whenever I build the project I get the error message below,

```
Ld /Users/shade/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ResSim-fvkhqxhiupiizxgffxqgoxgolsmv/Build/Products/Debug/ResSim normal x86_64 cd /Users/shade/Dropbox/School/Gwinnett_Tech/CIST_2362/final/ResSim setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.8 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -L/Users/shade/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ResSim-fvkhqxhiupiizxgffxqgoxgolsmv/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/shade/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ResSim-fvkhqxhiupiizxgffxqgoxgolsmv/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/shade/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ResSim-fvkhqxhiupiizxgffxqgoxgolsmv/Build/Intermediates/ResSim.build/Debug/ResSim.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ResSim.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -stdlib=libstdc++ -o /Users/shade/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ResSim-fvkhqxhiupiizxgffxqgoxgolsmv/Build/Products/Debug/ResSim
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "party::getArrival()", referenced from: restaurant::startSim() in restaurant.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
"party::getArrival()", referenced from: Restaurant::startSim() in restaurant.o Symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is a new error message since it was working earlier today/this weekend in visual studio. But I've changed a decent amount of code since then, the code in the gist has been updated and is what I'm working with. I'm currently trying to get it to build in xcode so I can finish debugging/programming my project that is due tonight. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: In the future, please post the relevant code in your question instead of linking to it. It will probably help you to create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) first.

Answer (score 2):

You do not define `getArrival` in your `party.cpp` file. You probably want:

```
int party::getArrival(){
    return arrival;
}
```